# Can't convert a Base64 to MemoryStream

Tags: c#

I'm having some issues in converting an image from an Base63 string to image memoryStream on a WebApi. The result looks like this:  [image]

I have tried several ways ala this:

```
            var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pagedResult.Data);
            var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            var image = await Image.LoadAsync(ms, cancellationToken);
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            await image.SaveAsync(stream, new JpegEncoder(), cancellationToken);
            stream.Position = 0;
            ms.Position = 0;
            
            return (stream, pagedResult.Mimetype);
```

Or something as simple like this:

```
            var sapDoc = Convert.FromBase64String(pagedResult.Data);
        return (new MemoryStream(sapDoc), pagedResult.Mimetype);
```

The controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet("document")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Stream>> GetImage([FromQuery] long documentNumber, string documentId)
    {
        var query = new GetDocument.Query
        {
            DocumentId = documentId,
            DocumentNumber = documentNumber
        };

        var (image, imageFormat) = await _mediator.Send(query);
        return File(image, imageFormat);
```

Any idea what's going on?
I have verified the base64 string. If i take the output and use forexample this: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter i can see the image.

Comment: What are you using to view "the result"?

Comment: @Crowcoder Im using PostMan.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I was the mimType that from SAP was set to JPG instead of JPEG. An simple `mimType.Replace("jpg", "jpeg")` fixed the issue :)

Answer (score -2):

Here is a way to do it:

```
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pagedResult.Data);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: You are just using a different constructor than  OP, how does this answer the question?

Comment: If is highly unlikely that the image is encoded as UTF8; the OP said it is Base64-encoded.